# HTML Появляются прозрачные границы между ячейками таблицы переменной ширины при использовании градиентной заливки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется, допустим, такая вот таблица с таким стилем:

```html
<style>
table{
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(50, 50, 50), rgba(200, 200, 200));
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Если менять размер таблицы, а точнее размер окна, от которого зависит размер таблицы, то проявляются прозрачные границы между ячейками. Если открыть этот код на всю страницу и растягивать/сжимать окно, то видно как "моргает" эта граница:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я заметил, такое появляется когда размер таблицы зависит от внешнего блока (или страницы), причем меньше 100%, таблица расположена по центру и используется градиентная заливка строк. Я пробовал использовать border-collapse, cellspaсing, cellpadding и т.д. ничего не помогло.

Как избавиться от этой границы, сохранив при этом другие свойства, как градиент и центрирование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поздравляю, вы нашли, скажем так, `баг` в `css`. По идеи можно сделать так.

```css
td + td {
  transform: translateX(-1px);
}
td {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(50, 50, 50), rgba(200, 200, 200));
}
```

```html
<style>
table{
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

tr {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(50, 50, 50), rgba(200, 200, 200));
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Для данного примера это сработало, но, к сожалению, когда я писал вопрос я максимально все упростил. А вообще у меня используется наклонный градиент и второй цвет в нем с прозрачностью: `linear-gradient(1deg, rgb(50, 50, 50), rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.8)` В этом случае такой костыль уже не помогает. Но, похоже тут уже придется смириться. Пожалуй упрощу немного свой стиль, сделаю градиент без наклона и прозрачности. Спасибо большое за ответ, отмечу его как решение (хотя, если у Вас появятся идеи как победить эту проблему с более сложным градиентом, буду очень рад )) )